# Residue of Function

Tags: complex-analysis

I need help finding the residue of the following function at $z=\pi$:

$$\exp\left(\frac{2}{z-\pi}\right)$$

I have put the function into a series expansion about z=pi by using the expansion of $e^x$ and the using $x=\frac{2}{z-\pi}$. But the expansion is infinite in decreasing powers of $z-\pi$ - does this mean the point $z=\pi$ is an essential singularity and if so how do I go about finding the residue at that point - is it just 2 (i.e. the coefficient of the term with $(z-\pi)^{-1}$)?

Comment: Yes, it is an essential singularity, and the residue is the coefficient of $(z-z_0)^{-1}$ in the Laurent expansion, whether the singularity is a pole or essential.

Comment: Yes, @msd27: it is .

Comment: @DonAntonio thanks!

Answer (score 1):

More generally: if $f$ is entire, then the residue of $f(a/(z-z_0))$ at $z_0$ is $a f'(0)$. Independent of $z_0$, as it turns out.